# Как мне поставить React на Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

Пытаюсь поставить React  на laravel, чтоб во view можно было использовать его методы, классы и.т.д.
Вот алгоритм по которому пытаюсь это сделать:

1. Находясь в папке с чистым laravel проектом прописываю `npm install`
2. Устанавливаю react `npm install react` и `npm install react-dom`
3. В webpack.mix.js прописываю `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').react()`
4. В resources/js/app.js прописываю `import React from 'react';` и `import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`
5. Запускаю `npm run dev`
6. На странице подключаю скрипт public/js/app.js `<script src = "/js/app.js"></script>`
7. Там же размещаю скрипт для проверки работы `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); root.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);`

Как итог - нечего не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

Comment: Диагноз `нечего не работает` в корне не верен.. `Ничего не работает - это когда в розетке нет электричества.` По выполненным вами действиям вроде все верно, но.. какую ОШИБКУ вы получили на выходе? Покажите что в package.json, покажите что вам пишет в консоль браузера. Как вы поняли что у вас ничего не работает...

Comment: alert'om выбрасывал js метод который возвращает все методы объекта (React  в данном случае) страница просто не видит этой переменной

Comment: Тут вроде все написал, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115640/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-js-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-laravel/1115654#1115654